# Laravel Websockets + React Native

Tags: laravel, react-native, websocket

I cannot connect to Laravel's websocket from my ReactNative application. I have practically tried all npm packages that contain the words "pusher", "websockets", or anything similar, but none of them work and I am starting to get desperate.

For example, I have several packages stacked up in my package.json file such as:

```
"react-native-use-websocket": "^0.2.6",
"react-native-websocket": "^1.0.2",
"laravel-echo": "^1.15.0",
"pusher-js": "^8.0.1",
// No one worked for me following the oficial docs...
```

... Does anyone have a configuration that will work in any way? I am really about to throw my computer out the window.

In Laravel, everything works fine, that is, starting the websocket server and testing with Tinker, I can see perfectly on "http://127.0.0.1:8000/laravel-websockets" how the message is sent, but in the React application, I can't even get close.

Can someone kindly help me?

Laravel config (which works perfectly is:)

*env

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
//...
PUSHER_APP_ID=12345
PUSHER_APP_KEY=ADDADD123123
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=ADASADAS123123
PUSHER_HOST=127.0.0.1
PUSHER_PORT=6001
PUSHER_SCHEME=http
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

*NewMessage.php

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel>
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        // return [
        //     new PrivateChannel('channel-name'),
        // ];
        return new Channel('home');
    }
}
```

I can't show my React code because none of the options have worked in any way. I just want to be able to see the message, the first connection, the minimum hello world.. but there's no way. What options do I have besides shooting myself?

If i try this:

```
import Pusher from 'pusher-js/react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

const PusherTest = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const pusher = new Pusher('ADDADD123123', {
      cluster: 'mt1',
      encrypted: true,
      wsHost: '127.0.0.1',
      wsPort: 6001,      
    });

    const channel = pusher.subscribe('home');

    channel.bind('App\\Events\\TestEvent', (data) => {
      console.log('Received event:', data);
      setMessage(data);
    });

    return () => {
      pusher.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>Hi</Text>
      <Text>{message}</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
};

export default PusherTest;
```

I get an error that says:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Buffer
```

And its a npm package error, not mine. So let's try another way:

Let's try with socket.io:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

const SOCKET_SERVER_URL = 'http://localhost:6001'; // URL del servidor de WebSocket

const WebSocketTest = () => {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const socket = io(SOCKET_SERVER_URL);
        
        socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('Conectado al servidor de WebSocket');
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log('Desconectado del servidor de WebSocket');
        });

        socket.on('message', (data) => {
            console.log('Mensaje recibido:', data);
            setMessages((messages) => [...messages, data]);
        });

        return () => {
            socket.disconnect();
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <Text>Hi</Text>
            {messages.map((message, index) => (
                <Text key={index}>{message}</Text>
            ))}
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

export default WebSocketTest;
```

I get no response, and I can't find in the documentation where to assign the name of the channel I want to subscribe to.

Comment: Can somebody help me here ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this with the use of the package `laravel-echo`.
I defined the Pusher instance in the Echo options (since in react native you cannot set the global `Pusher` instance by assigning it to `window`). This is the basic implementation that I used.

```js
import Pusher from 'pusher-js'
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

export default const Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    Pusher, // sets the instance imported above

    // Tweak the options according to your settings
    key: '', // set the key defined in your .env
    wsHost: 'localhost', // the host defined in your .env
    wssHost: 'localhost', // the host defined in your .env
    wsPort: 6001, // or the port defined in your .env
    wssPort: 6001, // or the port defined in your .env
    forceTLS: false,
    encrypted: false,
    cluster: 'mt1',
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss],
})
```

Then you can listen for the events as you normally would in your Laravel frontend.

```
import Echo from '/path/to/above/file';
import {useEffect} from 'react';

function YourComponent({yourProps}) {
  // your hooks and functions...

  useEffect(()=>{
    Echo.channel('your-channel')
      .listen('YourEventName', (eventData) => {
        // do something when the event fires
      });
  },[])

  return (<>{/* Your Component */}<>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@based of the first answer

pusher-js is not compatible with react native.
use pusher-js/react-native.

Use this code :

```js
import {Text, AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import Pusher from "pusher-js/react-native";
//import Pusher from 'pusher-js' no es compatible con react native  ya que react native no tiene elementos html DOM
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

const connectToWebSocket = async () => {
    
      try {
        const ws = new Echo({
          broadcaster: "pusher",
          Pusher, // sets the instance imported above

          
          key: "app-key", // app key
          wsHost: "192.168.1.4", // host
          wssHost: "192.168.1.4",
          wsPort: 6001, // port
          wssPort: 6001, 
          forceTLS: false,
          encrypted: false,
          cluster: "mt1",
          enabledTransports: ["ws", "wss"],
        });

        console.log(ws);
        const channel = ws.channel('test-event');
        channel.subscribed( () => {
          console.log('subscribed');
      
      }).listen('.test-event', (e) => {
         console.log("Escuchando Evento :",e);
      });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
      }
    };

    // Llama a la función para conectarte al servidor WebSocket local
    connectToWebSocket();
```